# Slide not in handouts (Powerdot presentation)

Tags: powerdot

My aim is to include a certain slide ONLY in the presentation, but NOT in the handouts generated by a Powerdot presentation (I have the authorization to show some results, but not to distribute them). Is there anyway to do it? How?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your typical input.

Comment: In what format are you producing your handouts? If it's one per side with room for notes, I'd be tempted to use pdftk to remove the offending page from the handout pdf.  This has the (IMO) advantage of acknowledging the missing slide by omission the break in numbering (though you might want to do more than that)

Comment: I was more interested in something I got used with Prosper. That package (Prosper) had the OnlyInPDF function, which allowed some contents to only appear in the PDF version (for presentation slides) but not in the PS version (for handouts). Unfortunately, Powerdot has nothing similar.